# Missing EXIF info in images selected from gallery using EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI

Tags: android, gps, exif, geotagging

I'm trying to gather EXIF info (date of picture taken, geotagging, orientation) from images selected from an EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI intent, but it seems that if the pictures come from the internet (e.g. Google Photos) the EXIF data is somehow truncated.

For example if I download a picture from a web browser from photos.google.com on my PC, its size is 4.377.104 bytes, and all the EXIF data are there.
While if I download the same exact image using the command:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
```

its size is 4.363.578 bytes (13526 bytes less than the original) and all the EXIF data are lost

Any idea on how to download the full original image?

PS: if I select a picture from the gallery which was taken from the phone and it is still resident on the phone's storage, the EXIF data are present

Answer (score 1):

I finally found out a solution. after getting the source image Uri in the onActivityResult method using

```
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
```

I use the following function to get the necessary data from the picture

```
public static ImageInfo getImageInfo(Context context, Uri photoUri) {

        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(photoUri,
                new String[] {
                        MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION,
                        MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.LATITUDE,
                        MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.LONGITUDE,
                        MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN } , null, null, null);

        if (cursor.getCount() != 1) {
            return null;
        }

        cursor.moveToFirst();

        ImageInfo i = new ImageInfo();
        i.Orientation = cursor.getInt(0);
        i.Lat = cursor.getDouble(1);
        i.Lon = cursor.getDouble(2);
        i.DateTakenUTC = cursor.getLong(3)/1000;

        cursor.close();

        return i;
    }
```

Comment: what it - ImageInfo?

Comment: It is a custom object containing the data I require